# Switch other toggles when one of it is on

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an array of toggles defined in script. They are all turned off in the beginning. When the user clicks on one of the toggles, that toggle should be turned on and the other toggles should be switched to off state. Basically there could be only "one" on state toggle. How do I achieve this?

Currently with this script, all the toggles are getting turned off when the user clicks on one of it.

```
public Toggle[] toggle;

 void Start () {
        for (int i = 0; i < toggle.Length; i++) {
            int idx = i;
            toggle[idx].onValueChanged.AddListener (delegate {
                ToggleValueChanged (toggle[idx], idx);
            });
        }
    }

    public void ToggleValueChanged (Toggle change, int index) {
       
        for (int i = 0; i < toggle.Length; i++) {
            if (i == index) {
                return;
            } else {
                if (toggle[i].isOn) {
                    toggle[i].isOn = false;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: seems like a good point for a debug-session. Just out a breakpoint into your handler and inspect the relevant variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your ToggleValueChanged function like this :

```
public void ToggleValueChanged (Toggle change, int index) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < toggle.Length; i++) 
    {
        if (i == index) continue;
            
        if (toggle[i].isOn) {
            toggle[i].isOn = false;
        }
    }
}
```

When you return in you first if statement, other toggles won't get off. you have to continue iterating your loop.
And instead getting the index and passing it to the delegate, you can use [RefrenceEqual](https://www.google.com/search?q=RefrenceEquals+unity&sxsrf=AOaemvL8-eBFPlKUWbOoITKN0jLJUXNEFQ%3A1632129026678&ei=AlBIYZLgKNKzkwXhvKuIAg&oq=RefrenceEquals+unity&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBAgAEA0yCAgAEA0QBRAeMggIABAIEA0QHjoHCCMQsAMQJzoHCAAQRxCwA0oECEEYAFD4CVj4CWCTDGgBcAJ4AIAB5AGIAeQBkgEDMi0xmAEAoAEByAEJwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwiS6fK2mo3zAhXS2aQKHWHeCiEQ4dUDCA4&uact=5)

**EDIT**
Actually each time you manipulate the toggle[i].isOn, you are changing the value of it. So each time, You are calling your function.
**EDIT** 
try this :

```
public void ToggleValueChanged (Toggle change, int index) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < toggle.Length; i++) 
    {
        if (i == index) continue;
            
        if (toggle[i].isOn) 
        {
            toggle[i].SetIsOnWithoutNotify(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I added ```toggle[i].isOn = true; continue;``` but it is causing a stackoverflow and my Unity hangs.

Comment: Oh sorry, don't change toggle value inside this function. It makes recalling the function each time you set toggle[i].isOn = true; I will edit my answer

Comment: I did try but unfortunately it does not work. It in fact switches off all the toggles.

Comment: You define onValueChanged for each toggle right? when you change the value of each one of them, you are calling this event. this is not the proper way to handle your situation.

Comment: Yeah you are right. What could be a best way to handle array of toggle states?

Comment: Read the updated answer.

Comment: Absolutely perfect! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: I was so free to make your code a bit better to read ;)

Answer (score 2):

Unity has a component called ToggleGroup that allow you to do just that.

**ToggleContainer Parent Object:**

[image: ToggleContainer GameObject]

**Reference ToggleGroup object in every Toggle component as following:**

[image]

**Scene Hierarchy:**

[image: Scene Hierarchy]

**Overview**:

https://gfycat.com/bossyscenteddorado

Comment: This is definitely the better (more automatic) way ^^ Have in mind though that this has one hard requirement: All toggles need to be directly nested within this group. Using a loop this is not the case

Comment: Just a note about Toggle Groups. They are great, but they can be inconveniently be partially ignored when using SetIsOnWithoutNotify() as it seems like SetIsOnWithoutNotify() only works with positive results. (You can't use SetIsOnWithoutNotify(false) with Toggle groups as if you would do it with .isOn)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you even need the index for this?

Simply do

```
 public void ToggleValueChanged (Toggle change) 
 {
     // add a little safety to actually only disable all others if 
     // this one ws actually enabled
     if(!change.isOn) return;

     foreach(var toggle in toggles)
     {
         if (toggle == change) continue;
         
         if (toggle.isOn) 
         {
             // I would actually specifically NOT use "SetIsOnWithoutNotify"
             // because you never know who else is actually listening to the state change
             // so if you simply set it to false but don't invoke the callback events
             // things might behave different than expected
             toggle[i].isOn = false;
         }
    }
}
```

and accordingly

```
foreach(var t in toggle)
{ 
    var currentToggle = t;
    currentToggle .onValueChanged.AddListener(value => ToggleValueChanged(currentToggle));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to either `return` or `continue`, just don't handle the toggle if it's the indexth one:

```cs
public void ToggleValueChanged (Toggle change, int index) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < toggle.Length; i++) 
    {
        if (i != index) 
        {
            toggle[i].isOn = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Also you can assume that all others are off, so no reason to check that either.

Comment: I did try but unfortunately it does not work. It in fact switches off all the toggles.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice it was the actual event handler and got called for all toggles. I'll leave the answer, though.

Answer (score 0):

If they are mutually exclusive, they aren't "boolean states", it's just one state, supported by an enum and including the null value. If your UI is a set of checkboxes, you should switch it to a set of radio buttons. A dropdown box would do as well.